# Unexpected space after expanding searchview

Tags: android, view

At the beginning, the SeachView works normally. After I switch to another fragment then go back then click on the search icon. The toolbar has been extended vertically as the picture below

[image]

Code snippet

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // listening to search query text change
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when query submitted
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when text is changed
                stationAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please check answers in given link below : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35695676/how-to-remove-space-on-the-left-side-of-android-searchview-which-is-not-part-of

Answer (score 0):

`android:paddingStart="-16dp"` //set dp as per your need

That's enough for post lollipop devices.